# What Is The Syntax Error In The Provided Code:

Tags: php, syntax

```
$pollPart .= '
<tr>
<td valign="top" nowrap="nowrap">'.$question['question'].'</td>
<td valign="top" height="10" width="100%" style="padding: 0px 10px;">
<table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
<tr>
<td valign="top" width="'.$percentage.'%" '.if($percentage > 0){$pollPart .= 'style="background: url(\'/includes/poll/images/bar.jpg\') repeat-x;"';}.'><img src="/includes/poll/images/dot.gif" width="1" height="19" /></td>
<td valign="top" width="'.$percentage2.'%"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
<td valign="top">'.$responses['total'].'</td>
</tr>
';
```

I am getting the Syntax on the following line:

```
<td valign="top" width="'.$percentage.'%" '.if($percentage > 0){$pollPart .= 'style="background: url(\'/includes/poll/images/bar.jpg\') repeat-x;"';}.'><img src="/includes/poll/images/dot.gif" width="1" height="19" /></td>
```

Specifically this part:

```
if($percentage > 0){$pollPart .= 'style="background: url(\'/includes/poll/images/bar.jpg\') repeat-x;"';}
```

Any input on this would be greatly appreciated, Thank You!

Comment: It should give you an error message and a line number. Please share the error message, than it's easier to explain. And yeah, just paste the error message into google as well, you might find some insightful discussions.

Comment: Hint: The if never ends.

Comment: You might want to consider using a templating system, or heredocs, or anything else than just putting your whole HTML in a string. Makes for confusing errors and hard debugging.

Comment: The script is not live as of yet, I know there is an error through dreamweavers' syntax highlighting. I have tried every combination under the sun but nothing will make the syntax highlight on that line go away. I will try make the script live now and see what error it makes.

Comment: @Xeon06 It is part of a simple polling script, the script is displayed when `$pollPart`is echoed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do if-blocks inside of a concatenation of strings. If you want to do an inline ternary if/else, the syntax is a little different.

Instead of

```
... if($percentage > 0){$pollPart .= 'style="background: url(\'/includes/poll/images/bar.jpg\') repeat-x;"';} ...
```

You would structure it like `CONDITION ? TRUE-PART : FALSE-PART`:

```
... (($percentage > 0) ? 'style="background: url(\'/includes/poll/images/bar.jpg\') repeat-x;"' : '') ...
```

I use an empty string (`''`) since no false condition is needed, but something needs to be returned in order to complete the statement and to concatenate with the rest of the string.

Alternatively, you can end your string of concatenations, place the if block after it, then start again with `$pollPart .=`.

Answer (score 4):

You can't use if condition inside of string that is assigned into variable. You can try:

```
(($percentage > 0)?'style="background: url(\'/includes/poll/images/bar.jpg\')':'')
```

Comment: I'm glad that my answer was useful ^^

Answer (score 1):

```
$pollPart .= '
<tr>
<td valign="top" nowrap="nowrap">'.$question['question'].'</td>
<td valign="top" height="10" width="100%" style="padding: 0px 10px;">
<table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
<tr>
<td valign="top" width="'.$percentage.'%"';

if($percentage > 0){
    $pollPart .= ' style="background: url(\'/includes/poll/images/bar.jpg\') repeat-x;"';
}

$pollPart .='><img src="/includes/poll/images/dot.gif" width="1" height="19" /></td>
<td valign="top" width="'.$percentage2.'%"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
<td valign="top">'.$responses['total'].'</td>
</tr>';
```